# Save local on close?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a new developer writing a simple Google chrome extension that track amount the amount of time a user spends on a given website each day. I think it is necessary for the extension to save the data. I don't have a good grasp of when the optimal time to save data is, but intuitively it seems whenever the user closes the browser is an important time. I have given permissions in the `manifest.json`

To begin I am starting with trying to save a dummy `object` locally.

In my `background.js` file I have:

```
chrome.app.window.onClosed.addListener(function(){  // attempt to save data
    chrome.storage.local.set({"ss": 2}, function(){
        console.log("saved")
    }) 
})
```

This is giving me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClosed' of undefined`

Comment: `chrome.app.window` is for [chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), not extensions. Simply save the data each time it's updated, otherwise you'll lose it on browser crash or power loss.

Comment: 1) thanks for the app tip super helpful! 2) I was think about having the extension work at the second level -- is that too frequent. Is every minute too frequent?

Comment: Unless your computer is a i8086 from 1988 even 10 times a second is fine.